# how to fetch information using volley library in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I've a php file on a server, and I have to fetch the information but i don't know how to pass a parameter to the query.

For example, if I have this query: SELECT * FROM accounttable WHERE idaccount = 1, i want to pass this 1 as a parameter, how can i do?

```
 val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, Response.Listener<String>{ s ->
        try {

                val array = JSONArray(s)

                for (i in 0..array.length() - 1) {
                    val objectAccount = array.getJSONObject(i)
                    val account = Account(
                            objectAccount.getString("accountplace"),
                            objectAccount.getString("useraccount"),
                            objectAccount.getString("accountpass"))

                    listAccounts.add(account)

                }


        }catch (e: JSONException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }, Response.ErrorListener { error: VolleyError? -> Log.e("error", "error")  })

    val  requesQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    requesQueue.add<String>(stringRequest)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to override the [`getParams()`](http://javadocs.okadatech.com/javadoc/volley/reference/com/android/volley/Request.html#getParams()) method on your `Request`. In order to do that you can either subclass `StringRequest`, or create an [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) (similar to an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) from Java); as shown below.

```
val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, Response.Listener { s ->
    // Your success code here
}, Response.ErrorListener { e ->
    // Your error code here
}) {
    override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> = mapOf("idaccount" to "1")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Can you explain me why you have to write object : StringRequest? Because without this, I couldn't override the getParams method

Comment: @zasaz That is the syntax for an object expression (which, as I mentioned above, is the replacement for Java's anonymous class declaration); it is the only way to create an object of an anonymous class in Kotlin. As for *why* the language designers went with that specific syntax, no clue.

Comment: @Bryan How do you add `stringRequest` to queque?  `queque.add(stringRequest)` rise an error `Expecting a class body`

Comment: Your suggestion has helped me to set headers & params in volley using Kotlin
Thanks to you